# How can I convert my offline account to an online account?

Tags: test-drive-unlimited-2

In Test Drive Unlimited 2, I've started my account in "Offline Mode". I've progressed pretty far, and now I want to add the online account to it.

What can I do?
Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming you're talking about the GFWL account. You cannot convert an offline profile to an online one while preserving the save files. Whether converting just the icon and the nametag makes sense or not is a different question.